# How to share function result in template?

Tags: angular

I try to do the following:

```
   <div *ngIf="getLastSignator(appdocspacket?.headappdoc?.signators) as lastSignator">
       <i *ngIf="lastSignatorr.issign > 0" class="fa fa-check"></i>
   </div>
```

Method is:

```
   public getLastSignator(signators: any[]) {
        return signators[signators.length - 1];
    }
```

How to do that properly?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If your outer div is true, then your inner div will be displayed - there is no need for a second *ngIf check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to avoid using functions calls from HTML template [due to the performance](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496). So the code would look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="appdocspacket?.headappdoc?.signators as foo">
    <i class="fa fa-check" *ngIf="foo[foo.length - 1] as bar">      
        {{ bar | json }}
    </i>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';  
  appdocspacket: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appdocspacket = {
        headappdoc: {
          signators: [
            {firstName: "1", lastName: "1"}, 
            {firstName: "2", lastName: "2"}, 
            {firstName: "3", lastName: "3"}, 
            ]
        }
    };
  }
}
```

[The whole stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsjpvm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Problem is I need to return last element of array from iteration ngFor, how to do that in component like get lastSignator()?

Comment: Could I use like this `foo[foo.length - 1] as last`     ->  `{{last.name}} {{last.secondname}}`?